# Validation.Type throws error 1004

Tags: validation, excel, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to use this code, based on code I found online, to prevent data validation being overwritten by copying and pasting into cells with data validation defined on them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Does the validation range still have validation?
    If HasValidation(Range("D3:D4")) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Application.Undo
        MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
        "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub

Function HasValidation(r) As Boolean
'   Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    x = r.Validation.Type
    If Err.Number = 0 Then HasValidation = True Else HasValidation = False
End Function
```

However, it always triggers an undo and the error dialog, even if I try to edit an unrelated cell, and if I comment out the `On Error Resume Next`, I can see that the line

```
x = r.Validation.Type
```

is failing with error 1004.

Comment: I don't see usage if `x`.

Comment: True. The only purpose of that line is to trigger an error, or not.

Comment: You always check validation on `D3:D4`, regardless of which cells you edit. If `D3:D4` do not have validation, you get an undo. What is not as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occured because I had updated the error message of the data validation in one cell but not the other.

When I copied and pasted the error message into the data validation of the other cell in the range, this problem went away.

Conclusion: Make sure that the data validation is defined in exactly the same way, including error messages, for all cells in the range.

Answer (score 0):

If you use data validation ranges with different rules/lists, you need to check them separately too (don't define a discontinuous union validation range as input to the HasValidation function) - otherwise it will through the error 1004 too.

```
'Does the validation ranges still have validation? Need to be checked seperately, otherwise error 1004
If HasValidation(Range("ValidationRangeA")) = True And _
HasValidation(Range("ValidationRangeB")) And _
HasValidation(Range("ValidationRangeC")) And _
HasValidation(Range("ValidationRangeD")) Then
         Exit Sub
Else

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    MsgBox "Your last operation was canceled." & _
    "It would have deleted data validation rules.", vbCritical
End If
```

End Sub